# Trying to find the parent-class of RDFNode objects in jena api

Tags: java, class, jena, ontology

I am using Jena java api to search in an ontology, and I use the command

`Property predicate=model.getProperty("propertyURL");
NodeIterator objects = model.listObjectsOfProperty(predicate);`

to find all the instances of a specific property,
where `model` is the OntModel where the ontology file is loaded.

Now, I need to find the parent-node/class where these instances belong to.
As the objects are RDFNodes, I tried the method `RDFNode.getClass()`, but it just returns  `class com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl`, which is not what I need.

I need something similar with `Individual.getOntClass()`. I also tried to convert the RDFNode-objects to Individuals and then use this function, but in this case it seems like the class is not saved during this transformation, because it returns the #Thing class (which is the one above all).

Any ideas on how I can get the class of the objects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there are some misconceptions to clear up in your understanding of Jena, but it would be much easier to do that, and to answer your question, if you edit the question to provide a sample of the RDF data you're trying to process.

Comment: @Ian first of all thanks for your interest to help :) My owl file is really big so unfortunatelly it's kind of hard to provide a sample.
I edited the question though, adding some extra details. I hope they are helpful. In case my question is not set well enough, providing that `model.listObjectsOfProperty()` returns RDFNodes which are leaves of the ontology-tree, what I am trying to do is to get the parent-classes they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to know if this answers your question without seeing the data, but there may be a simple explanation.

In OWL and RDF, a class is simply a set of resources (e.g. `:Cat` is the set of all cats, `:Tabby` is the set of all things with tabby colouring), and a resource can be a member of many sets (a tabby cat would be a member of both of those example sets). What this means in practice is that a resource *may* have, and in practice typically *does* have, more than one `rdf:type`. The method `OntResource.getRDFType()` only returns a single resource denoting a class, so in the case of a resource with multiple types, `getRDFType` will just pick the first one it finds. As a programmer, you have no control over which one is picked, and there is no guarantee that you will get the same one each time (brief technical explanation: it depends on the behaviour of the indexes in whichever triple store you're using at the time). However, if you want to know *all* of the classes to which a resource belongs, not just some arbitrary one of them, use `OntResource.listRDFTypes()`, which will give you an iterator over all of them.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought that there may be more than one classes that an instance belongs to.

Comment: I am trying to use `OntResource.listRDFTypes()` function, but the results of `model.listObjectsOfProperty(predicate)` functions are RDFNodes and not OntResources. There is the function `RDFNode.asResource()`, to convert it to Resource, but I couldn't find a way to convert it to OntResource. Is there a way to convert it to OntResource, or is there a different way to do the same thing with RDFNode objects?

Comment: You can convert with the `.as()` method, e.g. `.as( OntResource.class )` or `.as( Individual.class )`.  See http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html#rdf-level-polymorphism-and-java for background.